# Regex to remove duplicate letters

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a document in Notepad++ where each line can have any combination of characters. For example:

```
RRGG
U
XB
UUGG
UG
```

What I would like, is a regex to remove any duplicate characters. So, given the above, I would be left with:

```
RG
U
XB
UG
UG
```

I've tried finding `([a-z])` and replacing with `\1` based on something I'd seen online, but I got nothing. I've even tried finding `([a-z])+`, but that just got me the last letter on the line(not sure why I thought that would work, other than I'm horrible at regex). I also don't want to get rid of any whitespace, or empty lines. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Find:

```
([A-Z])\1+
```

Replace with:

```
\1
```

Answer (score 0):

For me in a dutch text, generated with the duplex switch on:

find

(.){2}

replace

\1

Comment: [Doesn't work for me](https://regex101.com/r/g1JrOU/1), have you tried it?

Comment: you miss "\1+" after (.){2}