# Replace multiple same letters

Tags: php, regex

I need to preg_replace multiple same letters (only A-Z or a-z, not numbers) in a row with same three. Can anybody help me with a pattern string?

Example:

> Input: NO MEK PUCES CUDAK AVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV VASMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>
> Output: NO MEK PUCES CUDAK AVVV VASMAAA

Comment: You need to replace all but 3 letters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex to remove duplicate letters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885329/regex-to-remove-duplicate-letters)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using group (`([A-Za-z])`) and backreference (`\1`).

```
$text = "NO MEK PUCES CUDAK AVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV VASMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";    
echo preg_replace('/([A-Za-z])\1{3,}/', "$1$1$1", $text);
# => NO MEK PUCES CUDAK AVVV VASMAAA
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular expression with a backreference:

```
preg_replace('/(.)\1+/', '$1', $str);
```

`(.)` matches any character and puts it in a capturing group. `\1` is a reference to that same  group, and `+` qualifies the previous token that it may appear once or more. So this replaces any run of at least two identical characters by just one.

If you want more than one character retained, like your example suggests, you can use the following:

```
preg_replace('/(.)\1{2,}/', '$1$1$1', $str);
```

If you need to restrict the character set, then just swap out the `.` by a character class, e.g. `[a-zA-Z]`.

Comment: This I know, but its not correct. This will replace everything and only with single one. I need only A-Z, a-z.. And be replaced with three same letters.

Comment: Yes, thats now correct, also needed (.) to change to ([A-Za-z])

Comment: That's what I wrote in the last sentence, yes.