# Python regex remove double character from string

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to remove all non-characters and all characters that follow the same characters from a string.

The example input "ABBBbbcCCCD EF  ZZZU" should become
"ABCDDEFZU". In the filter2 function I try to capture a 
two-letter pair, so that I can compare the two letters. 
But I only match the real matched letter, not the look behind letter.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: latin-1

import re
testfield = 'ABBBbbcCCCD EF  ZZZU'
def filter1(matchobj):
  return ''
def filter2(matchobj):
  print('MATCH:' + matchobj.group(0))
  return matchobj.group(0)

print(testfield)

testfield2 = re.sub('[^A-Z0-9]', filter1, testfield, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(testfield2)

testfield2 = re.sub('[A-Z0-9](?=[A-Z0-9])', filter2, testfield2, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

How do I pass both letters to the *filter2* function but still find all possible matches?
    print(testfield2)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885329/regex-to-remove-duplicate-letters

Comment: How this  input "ABBBbbcCCCD EF ZZZU" will become "ABCDDEFZU", from where the 2 D come from.

Comment: @yoyi - because that was done manually... (I took the D out)

Comment: @cherhan - I'm trying to find out how to get the two letters into the "filter2" function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should raw your regex patterns. And second (assuming you meant `ABCDEFZU` as end result), using backreferences and a lambda function to return the uppercase letter of the matched part, you can do:

```
testfield2 = re.sub(r'([A-Z0-9])\1+', lambda m: m.group(1).upper(), testfield2, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(testfield2)
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/j1iMYz)

Comment: Regarding *rawing* I have not found out how to raw a pattern when the pattern in stored in a string. like `pattern="([A-Z0-9])\1+"` `testfield=re.sub(pattern...`

Comment: @576i It's just the same. You do `pattern = r"([A-Z0-9])\1+"`