# Remove duplicate number from each row in SQL

Tags: hana

I have this table:

```
A     B           C   
Abc.  Bcd.        1223     
Abc.  Bdh.        144777
```

I want to remove duplicates from each row in `C` column. Output should be like:

```
A     B       C   
Abc.  Bcd.    123   
Abc.  Bdh.    147
```

I am using SAP HANA so many functions of SQL does not work there.

Comment: When will people finally understand that "mysql" is not a fancy way of writing "SQL"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use regular expressions like here ([Regex to remove duplicate letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885329/regex-to-remove-duplicate-letters))?

```
select REPLACE_REGEXPR ('([A-Za-z0-9])\1+' in 'AA2234b23' 
                        WITH '\1' 
                        OCCURRENCE ALL) 
from dummy;
```

result:
**A234b23**